# How to fix "credential reinitialization in a setuid context ignored"?

Tags: 22.04, sudo, pam, kerberos

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Kerberos authentication. Every time I use `sudo`, the following error is logged by the system:

> pam_krb5(sudo:setcred): (user ****) credential reinitialization in a setuid context ignored

This does not happen in 20.04 with the same configuration. Does this indicate some configuration error on the system or the domain controller, or is it just noise that should be ignored?

```ini
[libdefaults]
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
```